# Website incoming http detection

Tags: httpwebrequest

Can anyone recommend a tool or technique that can help me detect and read the http cookies etc that my website receives and then acts on?

Answer (score 4):

Use Developer Tools.

If you are using a WebKit browser like Chromium or Opera, you should be able to right click on a page and click **Inspect Element**. There should be a tab for **Resources** and then on the side should be a button that says **Cookies**.

There are also a great many other resources for web designers in Developer Tools.

Firefox also has an extension called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network) that allows you to see HTTP headers.

IE may also work with **Firebug Lite**.

For seeing all packets on your network, check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). There are plenty of tutorials on the web on how to use it to extract HTTP header packets and browser data.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. Please permit me to ask what may be a silly followup question. I need a tool that will show me HTTP information sent from remote agents not just the current browser I am looking at. So, if I am using FireFox, IE, an Android or iPhone app, will the Chrome browser show me all that incoming information?

Comment: Not a silly question, but you're slightly unclear. To answer your question, no. HTTP data is routed to your browser when you _first_ request HTTP data from a remote server. You normally request that HTTP data through your browser by following URLs. If you want to see your HTTP information through Firefox, I'd recommend firebug: http://getfirebug.com/ . IE might be able to use Firebug Lite and I am not sure about Android phones, but I am sure you can find some apps that will do that.

Comment: Oh I just realized there's also Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/. You can actually see all your network traffic and extract the HTTP headers for analysis. There are plenty of tutorials all over the Internet and here at StackOverflow on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

It is a great tool, and also has a proxy that you can use to track traffic that is to/from processes other than your browser.

Comment: Why have I been downvoted on this - I thought it a reasonable answer